# Why does this bit of jQuery work on desktop but not on touch devices?

Tags: javascript, jquery, touch

I want to display a modal when the user is attempting to access the address bar (exit intent). Since there is no sure way to detect this (security reasons) I am assuming when the user is existing the page from the top he/she will try to access the address bar.

There is a plugin for this called Ouibounce but it doesn't work on touch devices, so I looked for other solutions. Found this on another post on StackOverflow:

```
$(document).on('mouseleave touchleave', function(e) {
    if(e.clientY < 0) {
      alert('y u leave from the top?');
    }
});
```

It works great on desktop but not touch devices even though I have the `touchleave` event on there. Any idea how to get it to work?

Comment: One possibility is that there are no physical places to touch a mobile device such that `clientY` is negative.

Comment: Touch events have a special [`e.touches` property](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/TouchEvent/touches).